# how to install Ckeditor on symfony 5?

Tags: symfony, ckeditor5, symfony5

I'd like to install CKeditor on my symfony project using symfony5

I tried to perform this tutorial but i didn't manage some parts. : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/installation.html

1/ i did this command with success:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle
```

2/ I didn't perform the Register the bundle parts cause it' already in my config/bundles.php (so i assumed the documentation wasn't up to date)

3/ I added this to my fileType.php

```
use FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;

class PropertyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
->add('description', CKEditorType::class)
```

And my twig file is behind but nothing appear in the description field which stay a classic textarea

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    {{ form_widget(form.description) }}
</div>
```

The rendered template display this in the source code:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
     <textarea id="property_description" name="property[description]" required="required"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/bundles/fosckeditor/";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (CKEDITOR.instances["property_description"]) { CKEDITOR.instances["property_description"].destroy(true); delete CKEDITOR.instances["property_description"]; }
        CKEDITOR.replace("property_description", {"language":"en"});
</script>
```

I've this in chrome console :

```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) new:95 Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
>     at new:95 :8000/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Thanks to all, i'm a bit lost with this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perform the `php bin/console ckeditor:install` documented [on this part](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/installation.html#download-ckeditor) ?

The 404 issue may come from the ckeditor.js not found therefore it's expected to fail with `CKEDITOR is not defined`. 
You can read the documentation for [the ckeditor install symfony command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/usage/ckeditor.html#symfony-command) to get more information.

Comment: Thanks, i may misread this part of documentation. it solved my problem so in symfony 5 :
1 - composer require friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle
2 - php bin/console ckeditor:install
3 - php bin/console assets:install public

Answer (score 8):

**Download the Bundle**

```
$ composer require friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle
```

**Register the Bundle**

Then, update your config/bundles.php:

```
return [

 // ...

FOS\CKEditorBundle\FOSCKEditorBundle::class => ['all' => true],

// ...

];
```

**Download CKEditor**

Once, you have registered the bundle, you need to install CKEditor:

```
$ php bin/console ckeditor:install
```

**Install the Assets**

Once, you have downloaded CKEditor, you need to install it in the web directory.

```
$ php bin/console assets:install public
```

**Configure Twig**

Then, update your /config/packages/twig.yaml

```
twig:
    // ...
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
    // ...
```

**Usage**

```
use FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;

$builder->add('field', CKEditorType::class, array(
    'config' => array(
        'uiColor' => '#ffffff',
        //...
    ),
));
```